# What's the new way to use different fragments for different tabs?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have been looking far and wide at different solutions for this problem: How do I show different things in different tabs with the ActionBar in Android?

[image: Tabs]

I have found a method: Using fragments as XML then put them as the layout for the different tabs. But most code that is posted is either outdated and deprecated or very complicated.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample_main);

    // Set the Action Bar to use tabs for navigation
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Add three tabs to the Action Bar for display
    ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Tab 1").setTabListener(this));
    ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Tab 2").setTabListener(this));
    ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Tab 3").setTabListener(this));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate menu from menu resource (res/menu/main)
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

// Implemented from ActionBar.TabListener
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // This is called when a tab is selected.
}

// Implemented from ActionBar.TabListener
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // This is called when a previously selected tab is unselected.
}

// Implemented from ActionBar.TabListener
@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // This is called when a previously selected tab is selected again.
}
```

This is a sample from Android providing an example for the ActionBar and its own capabilities. This would be a good start, except it's deprecated. And most either this or something else that's deprecated. So I am wondering, What's the new way to use different fragments for different tabs?

Comment: A good example can be found here: https://gist.github.com/talhahasanzia/84e44e831f9c5f9b14835a253f3614dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**# Try to follow below steps:**

1. Design your `activity_main.xml` with `Toolbar`, `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`
2. Design layout XML's your fragments that you want to show for each `Tab` content.
3. Use `FragmentPagerAdapter` to populate `Fragments` on `ViewPager`
4. Set `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `ViewPager` using `ViewPager.setAdapter(FragmentPagerAdapter)`
5. Use `TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(ViewPager)` to give ability to `ViewPager` to work with `TabLayout` functionalities.

Here is a complete [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout).

**# If you are using AndroidStudio**, then you can easily create it using default **TabbedActivity** template. Follow below Steps:

1. Open `AndroidStudio`
2. File > New > New Project
3. Give a project name > Choose `minimum SDK` versions then press `Next`
4. Select `TabbedActivity` then press `Next`
5. Choose `Navigation Style:`  `"Action Bar Tabs(with ViewPager)` > `Finish`

Hope this will help~